# The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect when processing an email with a screennshot in the mail body using a c# app

Tags: c#, mime

I have a c# algorithm which processes my company's support email requests. It processes all incoming mail and recognises them by email domain otherwise it doesnt process them with the automated system.

The app captures all attachments, the email subject, body, to, from etc. It then passes this into our SQL db and logs the information. It then replies to the email with an automated response which includes the original email body, subject, from and to address. The reply also includes a reference to the details just logged in our db for the customer to call for an update on the request.

The application falls over when an email comes in with a screen shot in the body of the email.

The code is below -

public class CCLHandler
    {
        private ExchangeHandler m_exchangeEm;
        private List LogOutput;
        const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
        private Configuration.Configuration ActiveConfiguration;

```
    public CCLHandler(ExchangeHandler exchangeEm)
    {
        m_exchangeEm = exchangeEm;
        ActiveConfiguration = new Configuration.Configuration();
    }

    public string NewCCL(EmailMessage CurrentEmail, string BrokerCode, List<ProcessLogRecord> LogOutput)
    {
        LogOutput.Add(new ProcessLogRecord("Creating a new CCL"));

        //TODO: line below causes an error in GetEmailAttachments when MIME content is loaded. - think this is for handling images in the email body

        ***CurrentEmail.Load(new PropertySet(ItemSchema.MimeContent));
        MimeContent mc = CurrentEmail.MimeContent;
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(ActiveConfiguration.GetConfiguration().NETWORK_FILE_LOCATION.ToString(), FileMode.Create);
        FileStream fs1 = new FileStream(ActiveConfiguration.GetConfiguration().NETWORK_FILE_LOCATION.ToString(), FileMode.Open);
        fs.Write(mc.Content, 0, mc.Content.Length);
        fs.Close();***

        string Attachments = "";
```

The app_config is as follows -

- 60000 support@relay.ie Processed Unrecognised RelayStaff support Relay2011 relay.ie 5 3 SPM 1 Medium - resolution due within 2 days 1 0 support 0 Normal Your support email has been processed and a member of staff will contact you shortly Automated reply to support email on -  Your support email has been processed and a member of staff will contact you shortly network location\uploads\ 10 Data Source=Relay-sql\SQL2008R2;Initial Catalog=relaynet;User Id=relaynet;Password=relaynet network location//mergerelaynets/supportEmail/supportUpateCCL.asp?Details= network location//mergerelaynets/supportEmail/supportSaveCCL.asp?customerCode= Email was not recognised and has been forwarded to support staff. Automated reply - CCL reference is

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Thanks,
Chris.
.NET Developer

Comment: The error message is as follows -

Comment: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Comment: the app config didnt all upload in my post. I can email it to any kind soul who can shed any light on this for me.